# Are there non-constant holomorphic functions with values only in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering if there's a non-constant holomorphic function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R},\quad \Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ s.t. for every $z\in\Omega$:$\quad f(z)\in\mathbb{R}$?

I think this claim isn't correct, because I can apply the Identity Theorem somehow, but I'm not sure what sequence can be applied.

Any help and would be appreciated!

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004672/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258154/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260988/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3949618/42969

Comment: No, there aren't

Comment: @MartinR Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ludwig: No problem – I simply did a Google search for “real valued holomorphic function constant site:math.stackexchange.com” :)

Comment: Hint : A real valued function of a complex variable either non differentiable or it's derivative is $0$.

Comment: Hint $2$ : A non constant holomorphic map is an open map.

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations provide the simplest solution, in my opinion.